# CUPS Printer Stalls at "Sending Data to Printer"

Tags: debian, printing, cups

This is related to a [previous problem](https://superuser.com/questions/471776/cups-causes-printer-to-click-and-doesnt-print#comment556216_471776.com), though the problem has changed significantly so, I have opened a new thread.

I'm trying to set up a Cannon iP4850 with Cups (for my Raspberry Pi) running on Debian.

I've got cups installed, then compiled the drivers for the Cannon taken from http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010893.asp

The drivers came in two parts the PPD (compiled and Cups picks up) and 'pstocanonij' with converts postscript to work with the printer (I assume).

However the printer now just stalls at: Idle - "Sending data to printer." whenever trying to print on it. I've set the log level to warn and there doesn't appear to be anything related showing up (I'm using print test page).

Error Log:

```
E [09/Sep/2012:15:26:29 +0000] Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol.
E [09/Sep/2012:18:50:06 +0000] SSL shutdown failed: Error in the push function.
```

Printer Info:

```
Description:    Canon iP4800 series
Location:   Lounge
Driver: Canon iP4800 series Ver.3.40 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: usb://Canon/iP4800%20series?serial=2239B2
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or what further debug info I can provide?

Comment: Did this setup EVER work?

Comment: @techie007 no I'm setting it up for the first time. The printer functions correctly when plugged into an OSX/Windows Laptop I can't get it working with Debian

Comment: Cups can be a complete dog to set up. Are you connecting via USB? Is there a hub involved? Which Debian distro are you using?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the same thing with a canon MP800 I can print a test page or two, but at some point a printed page stops half way and cups just reports 'sending data to printer' You can queue more jobs and cancel them but it wont print. Not only that the MP800 appears to crash and you cant turn it off without unplugging. I've no issues with the same printer and my windows laptop. Thanks
John

Comment: have you managed to get this working? I am gettig exactly the same symptoms with an Epson AL C 1100. Druver compiled for and on the pi and printer job stalled at sending data to printer. I have tried the munkeh's suggestion without success.

Answer (score 3):

In the error log it is trying to bind to an IPv6 address. You should check in cupsd.conf that `Listen ipaddress:port` is set to the local IPv4 address of the raspberry pi. It's likely that cupsd isn't even starting up because it's failing to bind to a port.

Comment: Will get back to you once I've had a chance to investigate!

Comment: I've added `Listen 192.168.0.5:631`, but still see the error: `Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol.` and `Avahi client failed, closing client to allow a clean restart`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that /etc/cups/cupsd.conf allows incoming connections from your local network by inserting a `Allow from <NETWORK-PART>.*`

here are are parts where I inserted the lines from my config file

```
#Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from 10.0.0.*
</Location>

#Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
Order allow,deny
Allow from 10.0.0.*
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
AuthType Default
Require user @SYSTEM
Order allow,deny
Allow from 10.0.0.*
</Location>
```

According to  [your comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/cups-printer-stalls-at-sending-data-to-printer/1993#comment12613_1993) you still have problems with a line like `Listen 192.168.0.5:631` ... 
  - are you sure you have restarted your cupsd with `sudo service restart cups`?

- Do you still have the `Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock` line afterwards? Without that it won't listen to incoming network connections at all I suppose.
- have you commented all other similar `Listen` lines like the following ... cups will only process the first one it finds.

I had these error logs with following possibilities, my cups version is 1.5.3, kernel 3.18.11+, debian_version 7.8, raspbian

- `Listen 10.0.0.*:631` ... Bad Listen address 10.0.0.*:631
- `Port 631` and `Listen *:631` ... Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol
- `Listen localhost:631` ... no error but Webinterface was not accessible anymore from remote pc.